# Display first even and then odd elements in a C++array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm a C++ newb. I need to insert numbers to an array and then display first the odd numbers and then the even numbers in a single array. I've managed to create two separate arrays with the odd and even numbers but now I don't know how to sort them and put them back in a single array. I need your help to understand how to do this with basic C++ knowledge, so no advanced functions. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int N{ 0 }, vector[100], even[100], odd[100], unify[100], i{ 0 }, j{ 0 }, k{ 0 };

    cout << "Add the dimension: " << endl;
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Add the elements: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        cout << "v[" << i << "]=" << endl;
        cin >> vector[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (vector[i] % 2 == 0) {
            even[j] = vector[i];
            j++;
        }
        else if (vector[i] % 2 != 0) {
            odd[k] = vector[i];
            k++;
        }
    }

    cout << "even elements are :" << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        cout << " " << even[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "Odd elements are :" << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        cout << " " << odd[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::sort` might be the simplest way how to sort a vector.

Comment: Note that `else if (vector[i] % 2 != 0)` could just be `else`. What exactly are you having problems with? Do you actually need to put the numbers back into a single array or do you just need to print them? What is the expected output of your program?

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match what you're asking. You already have all the numbers in `vector`, are you asking how to sort it?

Comment: I can't use C++ already built functions

Comment: @AlanBirtles the expected output would be if I enter 1, 2, 3, 4,5 as the arrays elements it should display 1,3,5,2,4

Comment: @SilviuStroe Then I have bad news, you are already using them, how do you think `<<` works? It's no different than `std::sort`.

Comment: This is very underspecified. These are questions you need to answer before solving this problem: Should you merge them into one array or just print them? If you should merge them, should it be into a new array or should you modify the input? Should the numbers be sorted, should they be in the same relative order as in the input, or will any order do?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to store the values then you can simply run through the elements and print the odd and the even values to different stringstreams, then print the streams at the end:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <iostream>

int main () {

  std::stringstream oddStr;
  std::stringstream evenStr;

  static constexpr size_t vecSize{100};

  int vec[vecSize] = {10, 5, 7, /*other elements...*/ };

  for(size_t vecIndex = 0; vecIndex < vecSize; ++vecIndex) {
    if(vec[vecIndex] % 2 == 0) {
      evenStr << vec[vecIndex] << " ";
    } else {
      oddStr << vec[vecIndex] << " ";
    }
  }

  std::cout << "Even elements are:" << evenStr.rdbuf() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Odd elements are:" << oddStr.rdbuf() << std::endl;
}
```

Storing and sorting the elements are always expensive.

Comment: @LouisGo I print the elements not the indices.

Comment: Sorry I misread it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it would be better to sort them first.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numbers[5];
    int mergedArrays[5];
    int evenNumbers[5];
    int oddNumbers[5];
    
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        cin>>numbers[i];
    }
    
    int temp=numbers[0];
    //bubble sort
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++) 
    {
       for(int j = i+1; j<5; j++)
       {
          if(numbers[j] < numbers[i]) 
          {
             temp = numbers[i];
             numbers[i] = numbers[j];
             numbers[j] = temp;
          }
       }
   
    }
    
    int nEvens=0;
    int nOdds=0;

    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++) 
    {
      
       if(numbers[i]%2==0)
       {
           
           evenNumbers[nEvens]=numbers[i];
           nEvens++;
          
       }
       else if(numbers[i]%2!=0)
       {
           oddNumbers[nOdds]=numbers[i];
           nOdds++;
        
       }
    }
    
    
 
    
    int lastIndex=0;
    //copy evens
    
    for(int i = 0; i<nEvens; i++) 
    {
      
       mergedArrays[i]=evenNumbers[i];
       lastIndex=i;
    }
    
 
    
    //copy odds
    for(int i =lastIndex; i<nOdds; i++) 
    {
      
         mergedArrays[i]=oddNumbers[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This has the same result as my code. I mean it displays the even and odd in 2 different arrays. How do I merge the results ?

Comment: @SilviuStroe does it matter? Just remove the `cout<<"\r\n";` and the output will be the same as if they're a single array?

Comment: @SilviuStroe, see the code update

Answer (score 0):

If you have to just output the numbers in any order, or the order given in the input then just loop over the array twice and output first the even and then the odd numbers.

If you have to output the numbers in order than there is no way around sorting them. And then you can include the even/odd test in the comparison:

```
std::ranges::sort(vector, [](const int &lhs, const int &rhs) {
            return ((lhs % 2) < (rhs % 2)) || (lhs < rhs); });
```

or using a projection:

```
std::ranges::sort(vector, {}, [](const int &x) {
 return std::pair<bool, int>{x % 2 == 0, x}; });
```

If you can't use `std::ranges::sort` then implementing your own `sort` is left to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the following solution. Thanks you all for your help.

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

   int N{0}, vector[100], even[100], odd[100], merge[100], i{0}, j{0}, k{0}, l{0};

   cout << "Add the dimension: " << endl;
   cin >> N;
   cout << "Add the elements: " << endl;

   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
   {

      cout << "v[" << i << "]=" << endl;
      cin >> vector[i];
   }

   for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
   {
      if (vector[i] % 2 == 0)
      {
         even[j] = vector[i];
         j++;
      }
      else if (vector[i] % 2 != 0)
      {
         odd[k] = vector[i];
         k++;
      }
   }

   cout << "even elements are :" << endl;

   for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
   {
      cout << " " << even[i] << " ";
      cout << endl;
   }

   cout << "Odd elements are :" << endl;

   for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
   {
      cout << " " << odd[i] << " ";
      cout << endl;
   }

   for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
   {
      merge[i] = odd[i];
   }
   for (int; i < j + k; i++)
   {

      merge[i] = even[i - k];
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
   {
      cout << merge[i] << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Bubble Sort Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/) to sort whole input. After sorting them using `if` and put `odd` or `even` numbers in start of `result` array and and others after them. like below:

> //Bubble Sort

```
 void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n)
    {
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            // Last i elements are already 
            // in place
            for (j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
                if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
                    swap(arr[j], arr[j + 1]);
    }
```

> // Insert In array

```
int result[100];
if(odd[0]<even[0])
{
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{result[i] = odd[i];}
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
{result[i+k] = even[i];}
}else
{
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
{result[i] = even[i];}
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{result[i+k] = odd[i];}
}
```

Comment: A better way would be to use a comparison where even number are less than odd numbers and so a single sort.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Yes it's better to sort whole input first and then using comparison and put them in `result` array. I edit My answer